# Why is rand_r not defined in std?

Tags: c++, random, std

I was wondering why I can't use `std::rand_r` when including `cstdlib`? Or, more generally, why are some functions in `cstdlib` in the global namespace but not in the `std` namespace?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`rand_r`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand_r) isn't part of the standard, it is a POSIX method.

> ```
> rand_r(): _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 1 || _XOPEN_SOURCE || _POSIX_SOURCE
> ```
>
> #### Conforming To
>
> The functions `rand()` and `srand()` conform to SVr4, 4.3BSD, **C89, C99**, POSIX.1-2001. The function **`rand_r()` is from POSIX.1-2001**. **POSIX.1-2008 marks `rand_r()` as obsolete.**

Even better, forget about `rand` and `rand_r` and use `std::mt19937` with the correct distribution (see [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random)).

Comment: @RobertJørgensgaardEngdahl: Didn't notice that, added it, thank you.